# Do we have a Non-JDBC driver to connect PostgreSQL v10 (has NoSQL capabilities) from Java? (OR Do we have any other alternatives?)

Tags: java, postgresql

Just to connect MongoDB (NoSQL) from Java, we are using "Mongo Java Driver" and I know that Posgres is a relational DB and we have a JDBC driver but instead I would need to know is there a driver like "Mong Java Driver" for Posgres? OR Do we have any other alternatives?

Comment: The only way to connect to a Postgres database through Java is using JDBC (and the Postgres JDBC driver). I don't understand the question, what exactly are you trying to do? What kind of "connection" are you thinking of? What is the problem you are trying to solve with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that a lot of the postgresql-only features (UUID/Json etc.) can already be accessed by JDBC, like this example if you want to insert json data:

```
String[] json = {"{\"customer_name\": \"John\", \"items\": { \"description\": \"milk\", \"quantity\": 4 } }",
 "{\"customer_name\": \"Susan\", \"items\": { \"description\": \"bread\", \"quantity\": 2 } }",
 "{\"customer_name\": \"Mark\", \"items\": { \"description\": \"bananas\", \"quantity\": 12 } }",
 "{\"customer_name\": \"Jane\", \"items\": { \"description\": \"cereal\", \"quantity\": 1 } }"};

try {
 String sql = "INSERT INTO sales VALUES (?, ?::JSON)";
 PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

 for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
  ps.setInt (1, i+1);
  ps.setObject (2, json[i]);
  ps.executeUpdate();
 }
 conn.commit();

} catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

there's no, to the extent of my knowledge, well-known/maintained postgres-only driver, I've only be able to find this https://github.com/benfante/libpq-wrapper which is basically a wrapper over the client C library

Comment: Thanks, good to know that there's a wrapper and now I'm checking about this wrapper. And need to check how complicated it is. :)